# V8 Android, creating the context causes ASSERT ... CHECK(object->IsJSFunction()) failed

Tags: android, v8

I've successfully compiled V8 javascript engine for Android as a static lib (libv8arm.a), and I can statically link it into my android native C++ app (using ndk-r5b).

On Android, when the V8 context is created I get this runtime assert ...

// Initialize the V8 context.

Local globals = ObjectTemplate::New();

context = Context::New( NULL, globals );

Fatal error in v8/src/objects-inl.h, line 1581

CHECK(object->IsJSFunction()) failed

When I embed V8 into the MacOSX version of my app, everything runs fine and I can execute javascript without any problems.  I've spent many hours diffing code and also looking at gcc command line args for building V8 for Android.  I'm stuck, and very near to hacking V8 code to pieces to figure it out.

Does anyone know what things V8 runtime initialization needs to get past Context::New() asserting?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:
I'm attempting to trap this problem by modifying the CAST_ACCESSOR macro...

```
extern int __cast_accessor_count /* = 0 */;

// in the cpp file where Context::New() is called 
//namespace v8 { namespace internal {
//int __cast_accessor_count = 0;
//}; };

#define CAST_ACCESSOR(type)                     \
  type* type::cast(Object* object) {            \
    __cast_accessor_count++;                    \
    if( !object->Is##type() ) { OS::Print( "CAST_ACCESSOR %d %s\n",     __cast_accessor_count, #type );  object->ShortPrint(); } \
    ASSERT(object->Is##type());                 \
    return reinterpret_cast<type*>(object);     \
  }
```

... and printing the value before and after calling Context::New() ...

```
printf( "__cast_accessor_count=%d\n", v8::internal::__cast_accessor_count );

// Create a new context.
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();

printf( "__cast_accessor_count=%d\n", v8::internal::__cast_accessor_count );
```

in my MacOSX test app, the output is

```
__cast_accessor_count=0  
(gdb) continue  
__cast_accessor_count=272875
```

on Android the output before hitting the assert is

```
__cast_accessor_count=0  
CAST_ACCESSOR 101980 JSFunction  
0x486c4135 <undefined>
```

searched through the V8 code to find where object->ShortPrint() is outputing "undefined" and I found this...

```
case ODDBALL_TYPE: {
  if (IsUndefined())
    accumulator->Add("<undefined>");
```

I'm wondering if ODDBALL_TYPE is emitted by the codegen, and its different for IA32 assembly and ARM assembly.  That might explain different initialization on each platform.

---

UPDATE2:
finally got a valid callstack...

```
0x001e3b4e:                PAUL_DEBUG_BREAK + 0x002e
0x0023d916:_ZN2v88internal10JSFunction4castEPNS0_6ObjectE + 0x0056
0x00251594:_ZN2v88internal7Genesis17InstallJSBuiltinsENS0_6HandleINS0_16JSBuiltinsObjectEEE + 0x0048
0x00250e6c:_ZN2v88internal7Genesis14InstallNativesEv + 0x05e8
0x0025241c:_ZN2v88internal7GenesisC1ENS0_6HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS_6HandleINS_14ObjectTemplateEEEPNS_22ExtensionConfigurationE + 0x01c4
0x0024ed5a:_ZN2v88internal12Bootstrapper17CreateEnvironmentENS0_6HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS_6HandleINS_14ObjectTemplateEEEPNS_22ExtensionConfigurationE + 0x0022
0x00247a46:_ZN2v87Context3NewEPNS_22ExtensionConfigurationENS_6HandleINS_14ObjectTemplateEEENS3_INS_5ValueEEE + 0x017e
0x001e3c02:    _ZN16JavascriptEngine4InitEv + 0x007a
```

arm-eabi-c++filt

```
v8::internal::JSFunction::cast(v8::internal::Object*)
v8::internal::Genesis::InstallJSBuiltins(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSBuiltinsObject>)
v8::internal::Genesis::InstallNatives()
v8::internal::Genesis::Genesis(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,     v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*)
v8::internal::Bootstrapper::CreateEnvironment(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>,     v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*)
v8::Context::New(v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>,     v8::Handle<v8::Value>)
JavascriptEngine::Init()
```

Comment: Which revision are you using? I checked all major branches and failed to find CHECK at that line in any of them.

Comment: I'm using the version of V8 from the Android source.  http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Comment: ok, I see it now. unfortunately it is JSFunction::cast() which is used in tons of places. Can you run your app under the debugger to get the backtrace?

Comment: No unfortunately you can't be sure that on device it fails on the very first call to JSFunction::cast() so this stack trace does not explain anything. Please run debugger on the device (http://source.android.com/porting/debugging_gdb.html) to catch the moment when it fails. (also next time please do not post stack trace directly into comments, but use something like gist.github.com).

Comment: ODDBALL_TYPE representation is the same for ia32 and ARM. Oddballs are created in Heap::CreateInitialObjects only once. You really need to figure out which JSFunction::cast() fails --- where exactly we get undefined but expect a JSFunction.

Comment: Very strange. Can you find the name of builtin which is undefined? Insert `if (builtins->GetProperty(*name)->IsUndefined()) name->Print();` after bootstrapper.cc:1323 [ Genesis::InstallJSBuiltins].

Answer (score 4):

libraries.cc is the answer.

On android, I was using the libraries.cc file which was generated for the macosx build. I fixed the problem on android by using the js2c.py tool to generate a new libraries.cc file for android.